# how to modify checkbox which located in datagridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridView inside of this datagridView. We have checkbox located.I can't make selected true or false this particular checkbox which located in datagridview.
I add checkbox inside of datagridview with following code

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn check = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
check.HeaderText = "Юклаш";
check.Name = "assing";

this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(check);
```

DataGridView has CellContentClick method which will work after clicking some of cells from dataGridView this looks following

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "assing") 
    {
        int order_id = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["id1"].Value;
        DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["assing"];
        chk.Selected = true;
//chk.Selected = true dosn't work

    } 
}
```

Here is a question: I can't make this checkboxcell selected or not selected. How can I make it selected because `chk.Selected = true` don't work ?????

Comment: You may need to leave the cell to make it show. Also: You need to change the `Value` and/or set the `TrueValue` to whatever you want to be true. Also: Don't mix up _selected_ with _checked_!

Comment: chk dosn't have method or field checked.

Comment: Never said it did. Just trying to tell you that checked != selected. No need to select a cell in the cellcontent event; it will always be selected after clicking it. __Selection__ is the blue backcolor!! - Since you are working with a checkbox cell you probably want it to be __checked__, no? For this use `chk.Value = true;`. Which only makes sense if the user doesn't do it himself by hitting the checkbox. btw: this event is tricky as only hitting the content, not the cell will trigger it..

Comment: Thank you very much it work for me

Comment: sorry How I can check checkbox's value true or false

Comment: If checked `Value` is `true`. Otherwise it is `false` or `null`.